# Screen rotation stops the video transmission

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, video-streaming

I am relatively new to the Flex/Air application development.

I am involved in development of an app that transmits and receives the video stream.

The bug that I am working on now is on Android device, when you are rotating the screen during video being played, the video just freezes after rotation is completed.

The class that is used for video streaming is `NetStream`.

I am not quit sure which peace of code I need to post here since there are really a lot of code involved in this whole video part.

My first assumption is that in process of screen rotation, Flex/Air just kills my stream, but now sure if that's true.

So, I am just wondering if anyone else had problem with video during rotation.

We also have separate function for audio and during rotation audio works pretty well.

So please any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you using `StageVideo`? For video on mobile, you definitely should be. Additionally, does this happen in release builds or just debug builds?

Comment: I haven't tried release yet, all the development is in debug mode now.

Comment: Try a test in release mode. Debug has some weird quirks at times.

Comment: Tried, didn't make a difference. But thanks tho

Comment: Actually I just realized that Stream is still alive, it's just video that is been frozen!

Comment: Are you using `StageVideo`? Using a `Video` object or a Flex `VideoPlayer` or `VideoDisplay` **is not** recommended for mobile applications. They should be used as a fallback to `StageVideo` *only*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pausing the stream before rotating and resuming after?  You might also be able to save the current location of the stream and re-init the stream at that point after rotation.  Just a couple of quick ideas.